# Java&Swing: why the componenet isn't added dynamically?

Tags: java, swing

The following is my code.

I think click the button, at least, a Color.CYAN block will be added into MainPanel, but it doesn't.

Could you please tell me how to achieve that? Thanks.

```java
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            final TestFrame mainFrame = new TestFrame();
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public TestFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        setTitle("Frame");
        setSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));
        final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        final JButton button = new JButton("Test");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
                mainPanel.add(new Unit());
            }
        });

        mainPanel.add(button);
        mainPanel.revalidate();

        add(mainPanel);
    }

    class Unit extends JComponent {
        public Unit() {
            setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            final Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2D.drawString("Hello World", 10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the answer below suggest to use a CardLayout. It does not "dynamically" add the component when you click the button. I think it will confuse the issue. If you give the component a preferred size and revalidate() the panel after adding the component all the components will be display in a row until they wrap to the next row. That probably isn't the layout you want, but its a start. You then change the layout logic.

Comment: @camickr: "Not sure why the answer below suggests using a CardLayout."  When someone with your level of Swing experience puts a Swing GUI together, you can add or remove as many components as you wish.  For a beginner,  adding and removing Swing components to a GUI is confusing.  It's much better for beginners to create a GUI and change the **contents** of the Swing components, rather than adding or removing Swing components

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, The OP is doing a simple test to add a component. Since a button is used it would appear the OP wants to add a new component each time the button is pressed.  Using the CardLayout does NOT support this functionality, so to state it is a better solution for adding multiple components is wrong/misleading. If on the other hand the answer is trying to "guess" that the OP's real requirement is to simply show a hidden component then it should also suggest that a button should not be used. A checkbox would be more appropriate to toggle the visibility state of the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Unit JComponent is likely being added to mainPanel in the ActionListener and thus the GUI, but it has no preferred size and so per the FlowLayout used by JPanels, it will size to [0, 0]. FlowLayouts (and most layout managers) do not respect a component's size but rather its preferredSize.  Also, `revalidate()` and `repaint()` need to be called on the container (mainPanel) after Unit has been added so that the layout managers can do their laying out of components and to allow the OS to clear dirty pixels.

To solve this, give it a preferred size, preferably by overriding `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` but by calling `setPreferredSize(...)` if you must, and by calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after adding the component to the container.

Better still, add the component to the container using a [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), but hide it by also adding an empty JLabel, again using a CardLayout, and then display the hidden component by calling `CardLayout.show(...)` from within ActionListener.

Side note: don't forget the super method within your painting method:

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // add this ****
        final Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2D.setFont(UNIT_FONT);
        g2D.drawString("Hello World", textX, textY);
    }
```

else you break the painting chain and may see unwanted artifacts or other problems

---

e.g.,

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            final TestFrame mainFrame = new TestFrame();
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainFrame.pack();
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public TestFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        setTitle("Frame");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));
        
        
        final JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        
        final JButton button = new JButton("Test");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            cardLayout.next(cardPanel);
        });
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(button);

        mainPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        mainPanel.add(cardPanel);
        add(mainPanel);
        
        cardPanel.add(new JLabel(), "Foo");
        cardPanel.add(new Unit(), Unit.class.getCanonicalName());
    }

    static class Unit extends JPanel {
        private static final int PREF_W = 100;
        private static final int PREF_H = 100;
        private static final Font UNIT_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 60);

        public Unit() {
            setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            final Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2D.setFont(UNIT_FONT);
            g2D.drawString("Hello World", 360, 350);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Better still, .. [`CardLayout`]"* Plus one.